# Cisco 3172 asks for LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG license to enable OSPF and PIM when they are LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG license features

Tags: cisco, layer3, cisco-nx-os, nx-os, license

I have several Nexus 3100 switches in which I use OSPF and PIM. Cisco says that these features are included in the LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG which is included by default in the switches.

```
Switch1# sh license
license_xxxxxxxxx_5_1.lic:
SERVER this_host ANY
VENDOR cisco
FEATURE LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG cisco 1.0 permanent uncounted \
        VENDOR_STRING=<LIC_SOURCE>NEXUS_PRODUCTION</LIC_SOURCE><SKU>N3K-BAS1K9</SKU> \
        HOSTID=VDH=xxxxxxxxxxx \
        NOTICE=<LicFileID>201609xxxxxxx00</LicFileID><LicLineID>1</LicLineID><PAK>N3K-C3172TQ-XLxxxxxxxx</PAK> \
        SIGN=xxxxxxx
Switch1# sh license usage
Feature                      Ins  Lic   Status Expiry Date Comments
                                 Count
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
16P_UPG_PKG                   No    -   Unused             -
32P_LIC_PKG                   No    -   Unused             -
NXOS_OE_PKG                   No    -   Unused             -
24P_N3K_LIC_PKG               No    -   Unused             -
48P_N3K_UPG_PKG               No    -   Unused             -
LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG         Yes   -   Unused Never       -
LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG   No    -   Unused             -
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Although, if I see the log I find these messages:

```
2018 Nov  8 12:47:05.724 Switch1 [11231]: !!!!!!  WARNING: 'LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG' LICENSE NOT FOUND ON THE SYSTEM  !!!!!!. You have tried to enable a licensed feature [ospf] without installing the 'LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG'
license, which has not been found on the system.
2018 Nov  8 12:47:05.724 Switch1 [11231]: If you have enabled this feature in error, please disable the feature. If you have not purchased the license, please contact your Cisco account team to order the license. It is in violation of
 Cisco's Terms of Use to use this feature without purchasing the license.
2018 Nov  8 12:47:05.724 Switch1 [11231]: !!!!!!  WARNING: 'LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG' LICENSE NOT FOUND ON THE SYSTEM  !!!!!!. You have tried to enable a licensed feature [pim] without installing the 'LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG' l
icense, which has not been found on the system.
2018 Nov  8 12:47:05.724 Switch1 [11231]: If you have enabled this feature in error, please disable the feature. If you have not purchased the license, please contact your Cisco account team to order the license. It is in violation of
 Cisco's Terms of Use to use this feature without purchasing the license.
```

The [Cisco NX-OS licensing guide](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/nx-os/licensing/guide/b_Cisco_NX-OS_Licensing_Guide/licensing_cisco_nx_os_software_features.html#__) says:

> Layer 3 Base Services Package
>
> LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG
>
> N3K-BAS1K9
>
> Static routing
>
> RIPv2
>
> EIGRP stub
>
> OSPFv2 (limited routes)
>
> PIMv2 (sparse mode)
>
> Note
>
> The Cisco Nexus 3164Q, 31128PQ, 3232C, and 3264Q switches and the Cisco Nexus 3100 Series switches in N9K mode run Cisco Nexus 9000 Series software and follow the Cisco Nexus 9000 license model. Therefore, these switches require the Layer 3 Enterprise Services Package (rather than the Layer 3 Base Services Package) to support routing protocols.

But I have confirmed that I'm in N3K mode:

```
Switch1# sh system switch-mode
!WARNING: switch-mode is not configured. Running in default  mode.
system switch-mode n3k
```

The output of `show version` is:

```
Cisco Nexus Operating System (NX-OS) Software
TAC support: http://www.cisco.com/tac
Copyright (C) 2002-2016, Cisco and/or its affiliates.
All rights reserved.
The copyrights to certain works contained in this software are
owned by other third parties and used and distributed under their own
licenses, such as open source.  This software is provided "as is," and unless
otherwise stated, there is no warranty, express or implied, including but not
limited to warranties of merchantability and fitness for a particular purpose.
Certain components of this software are licensed under
the GNU General Public License (GPL) version 2.0 or
GNU General Public License (GPL) version 3.0  or the GNU
Lesser General Public License (LGPL) Version 2.1 or
Lesser General Public License (LGPL) Version 2.0.
A copy of each such license is available at
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.php and
http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html and
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-2.1.php and
http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/library.txt.

Software
  BIOS: version 3.5.0
  NXOS: version 7.0(3)I3(1)
  BIOS compile time:  01/25/2016
  NXOS image file is: bootflash:///nxos.7.0.3.I3.1.bin
  NXOS compile time:  2/8/2016 20:00:00 [02/09/2016 05:18:17]


Hardware
  cisco Nexus 3172T Chassis
  Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3227U CPU @ 2.50GHz with 8153496 kB of memory.
  Processor Board ID FOC20332ZW0

  Device name: Switch1
  bootflash:   14900224 kB
  usb1:               0 kB (expansion flash)

Kernel uptime is 4 day(s), 0 hour(s), 44 minute(s), 31 second(s)

Last reset
  Reason: Unknown
  System version: 7.0(3)I3(1)
  Service:

plugin
  Core Plugin, Ethernet Plugin

Active Package(s):
```

I'm experiencing problems with PIM and would like to be sure that they are not related with this.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Comment: I dont get it, it says exactly what you need on the link you provided. PIM is only Sparse-mode, which is enabled directly on the layer 3 VLAN/interface. It only allows the flow of multicast traffic.

Comment: Yes, I have enabled both PIM and OSPF features, but the log says "You have tried to enable a licensed feature [pim] without installing the 'LAN_ENTERPRISE_SERVICES_PKG'" for both of them.

Comment: What software are you using? Please post output of `show version`

Comment: I have updated the post with the output of show version.

Comment: The log is being generated when you write `feature ospf`in config mode?

Comment: Those messages appear in the boot process. But yes, I have tried disabling and enabling the OSPF feature and the message is again generated when OSPF is enabled.

Comment: For OSPF i have no idea, why that wouldn't work. You should contact Cisco and ask them about it. For PIM, that feature is only available with the full license.

Comment: By any chance, do you have any VDC's configured?

Comment: @Cown, I have updated the post to include the full content of Cisco Licensing Guide about the features included in the LAN_BASE_SERVICES_PKG license, which includes both OSPF and PIM. Also I have no VDC's configured, the switches that we are using support only one VDC.

Comment: I know the features, but as it says, PIM is only sparse mode and not full multicast support. You should be able to configure PIM sparse mode without enabling the feature? Anyways in order to get the correct answers i would contact and ask Cisco.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85685/discussion-between-uat-and-cown).

Comment: I'm sorry i dont have time, at work currently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to bug:

[CSCuz14971    N3000 incorrectly requires Enterprise license for PIM and OSPFv2](https://bst.cloudapps.cisco.com/bugsearch/bug/CSCuz14971)

This is fixed in 7.0(3)I4(2) 7.0(3)I2(4) 7.0(3)F1(1)  and later.

Note that this is purely cosmetic, i.e. it does not affect the functionality of OSPF or PIM, so if you are experiencing a problem with PIM you need to look elsewhere.